# How to change a variable name into a single vector containing that name?

Tags: r, variables

I am using R and I want to change this:

```
variablename
```

to this

```
c("variablename")
```

I want to use the vector for a function that looks like this:

```
function.describe <- function(data,variablename){
...
a<-data[c("variablename")]%>%
summary()

return(a)
}
```

My goal is to insert only the variablename and the dataset to get the summary. I do not want to insert a vector into the function.
What do I have to add instead of the three dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, use `substitute` with `deparse` to convert the unquoted argument to `character`

```
function.describe <- function(data,variablename){
      variablename <- deparse(substitute(variablename))
  data[variablename]%>%
          summary()


}
```

-testing

```
> function.describe(iris, Species)
       Species  
 setosa    :50  
 versicolor:50  
 virginica :50
```

---

Or if we want to use `dplyr`, `select` with `{{}}`

```
function.describe <- function(data, variablename) {
      data %>%
           select({{variablename}}) %>%
           summary()
}
```

-testing

```
> function.describe(iris, Species)
       Species  
 setosa    :50  
 versicolor:50  
 virginica :50
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the second option! It is working!